How to Parse logfmt Error Messages in Datadog
I'm currently trying to parse logfmt messages using Datadog, but I'm running into some issues. Here's an example log message that we're trying to parse:
time="2024-11-25 10:07:11" level=ERROR logger=mycompany.gis.infra.maps_service msg="unable to parse the provided address" gis_source=maps_service correlation_id=xxxxx client_id=yyyyy project_id=zzzzz exc_info="Traceback (most recent call last):
  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/mycompany/gis/infra/maps_service.py\", line 95, in map_details_to_address
    return Address(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pydantic/main.py\", line 341, in __init__
    raise validation_error
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for Address
country
  value is not a valid enumeration member; permitted: 'CH', 'FR', 'AT', 'DE' (type=type_error.enum; enum_values=[<Country.CH: 'CH'>, <Country.FR: 'FR'>, <Country.AT: 'AT'>, <Country.DE: 'DE'>])"

The log is generated by our Python application using logfmter, and we need to extract details like the timestamp, error level, logger name, message, correlation ID, client ID, and project ID for monitoring purposes. However, we are especially struggling to properly parse and structure the exc_info part of the log.
We're using the standard Datadog pipelines and have tried applying various parsing rules, but the nested nature of exc_info is giving us trouble.
Could anyone provide advice for parsing this type of log message effectively in Datadog, especially the exc_info section?
Thanks in advance!
